# Big Commerce - Custom Field Java Script Effecting Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, bigcommerce

I'm creating a custom form using EmailMeForm and using the full code option that uses CSS, JavaScript, and HTML. I embedded the code into the page content box and found that part of the JS code from EmailMeForm (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js) was causing my navigation menu's CSS styles to become hidden. The JS isn't very descriptive of what is what each section is controlling.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea of how to contain the scope of my Javascript to just the section of HTML added to the page content section

This is what I could find with the inspector for CSS code for the section.
I have no means of editing it myself. What ever is in the JS is making all of the style attributes in the CSS class to display as "none".

```
.Left #SideCategoryList .BlockContent, .Left .slist .BlockContent {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li a, .Left .slist li a, .Left .afterSideShopByBrand a, .Left #GiftCertificatesMenu li a, .Left #SideAccountMenu li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li li a, .Left .slist li li a {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size:13px;
    background:#f3f3f3;
    padding:7px 14px 7px 35px;
}
.Left #SideCategoryList li li li a, .Left .slist li li li a {
    background:#ececec;
    padding-left:50px;
```

All I want to know is how to isolate what goes in the page content section from the code embedded in the Big Commerce software.

Comment: Seems like you need to contact someone who knows both CSS and JS to resolve your issue. I don't think you're providing enough information on both the HTML/CSS nor the JS side to get an answer.  Your question basically asks, I added some stuff to my page and it's conflicting with what I had, how do I make it not conflict? Valid question, but not enough details. You would need someone experienced with JS and CSS to see if either of those two is causing things to hide. If you can't, get comfy with Chrome's Inspector and looking closely at the CSS of items that are hidden, then tracing backwards.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Right now it's difficult to understand what you're asking, since we cannot replicate your problem. Please provide the minimum code necessary so we can understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'll keep trying on my on my own then... I don't know what specifically is causing it, so I guess since I can be specific enough, no one here can help me...

Comment: Cthulu- this is easily reproducible. If anyone creates a web page in Big Commerce and sticks the js code in the page content section is will break the navigation pane created using the Big Commerce navigation menu options. I need someone who is familiar with creating custom forms on big commerce

Comment: This sounds like a JavaScript conflict. The odds of having conflicting CSS between the nav menu and the custom form are slim. Are you including the jquery library twice?